# Simple Discrete Control System in Simulink

Tags: discrete-mathematics, control-theory

Attached is a picture of a simple control system in both $s$-domain and $z$-domain (bottom half is in $s$-domain, top half is in $z$-domain). I can't seem to get the $z$-domain version to work. I get an algebraic error loop unless I put in a $z^{-1}$ delay state, but I shouldn't have to, right? Even then the answer looks wrong. Sample time is $0.2$ so $e^{-2 \times 0.2}\approx0.67$.

Sorry, but I have never done a discrete control system in Simulink, and I am hoping someone will point out the obvious. Thanks!

[Control system.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prASo.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

How are you coming up with your discrete time model? For the plant, $G(s) = \frac{1}{s+2}$, the discretized plant using a zero-order hold on the input with sampling time $T=0.2$ gives $G_d(z) = \frac{0.1648}{z-0.6703}$. Since you have a discrete-time model for your plant, $G_d$, your signals in this block diagram are discrete-time signals. Therefore, you shouldn't need a zero-order hold in the top loop. Furthermore, if your intent is to use integral control in both feedback loops, the discrete-time integrater should be of the form $C_d(z) = \frac{T}{z-1}$, where $T$ is the sampling time. When I implement these changes to your block diagrams and run the simulation, I find results that match up to what I'd expect.

The reason you get an algebraic loop error is because the block diagram you have results in a system that is not strictly causal (the transfer function is not strictly proper). For more on causality, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system), and more on proper transfer functions, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_transfer_function).

Comment: Thank you, sir, but I am afraid I don't quite understand.  Can't I just replace 1/[s(s+2)] with its z-transform, which for T=0.2 is (1 - 0.67z)/[(z - 1)(z - 0.67)]?  It sounds like you are saying I can ignore the zero-order hold that would be there in real life (does Simulink assume it is already there?).  Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: A zero order hold is used to convert a discrete signal into continuous one, which is then the input to a continuous system. Since the controller and system in your top loop are already in discrete time, you do not need a zero order hold. That being said, I'm not sure if including the zero order hold will affect the simulation, since Simulink might automatically discretize the continuous signal coming out of the ZOH in order to input it to the discrete time controller.

Comment: What exactly is the goal of your simulation? From the looks of your block diagrams, it seems as though you have a continuous system, $G(s) = 1/(s+2)$, and you're running integral feedback control in a simulation. It then looks like you're trying to discretize the system and again run integral feedback control for the discrete time equivalent system. Is this correct?